# How to install the package 'dpkg' from the AUR

Tags: arch-linux, dpkg, pacman

Today I installed Archlinux and I tried to install the following package 'dpkg' from the AUR. I tried 2 methods:

```
pacman -S dpkg
```

and after that failed I downloaded the *.tar.gz and tried:

```
pacman -U dpkg.tar.gz
```

At the first option I got the following error:

```
[root@localhost andreas]# pacman -S dpkg
Fehler: Ziel nicht gefunden: dpkg
```

and at the second option I got this error:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# pacman -U dpkg.tar.gz 
Lade Pakete...
Fehler: Fehlende Paket-Metadaten in dpkg.tar.gz
Fehler: 'dpkg.tar.gz': Ungültiges oder beschädigtes Paket
```

The error is in German and means "Invalid or Damaged Package".
I don't get why pacman can't find the package because it's here:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dpkg

I'm fairly new to Archlinux, I have mainly used Debian and its Derivates before.

Comment: Have you looked at [the AUR description on the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) ? The AUR doesn't contain any built packages.

Comment: Probably a better link if you are a native German speaker. https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Arch_User_Repository. (Lesen Sie auf Deutsch!) :)  The German version does not appear to have as much info, but may be easier to read. AUR is not officially supported, but is useful. `yaourt` is pretty good at helping with these packages.

Comment: 1. You need to read the wiki for the AUR. 2. Why would you want to install `dpkg`? At a guess, this is an XY problem.

Comment: I need dpkg to install Nero Linux, the problem is solved now.

Comment: the dpkg url return 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `dpkg.tar.gz` is the instructions to actually build the package.  Do this, in the directory in which dpkg.tar.gz resides:

```
tar xf dpkg.tar.gz
cd dpkg
makepkg
```

I had to resolve some dependencies with `pacman -S some-stuff` to get `makepkg` to finish.  I was left with a file `dpkg-1.16.15-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`.  That's the package file.  You have to do this to install it:

```
pacman -U dpkg-1.16.15-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Comment: Use `makepkg -s` to make it install the dependencies as well.

Comment: Thx it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler way: First check the AUR, to find the package "dpkg". You also would find a comment telling you to change the source URL. So, when I then used "trizen -S dpkg" (it installs from AUR) I was asked to edit the PKGBUILD say "y", so then I changed the source URL in the PKGBUILD file, and continued installation and everything worked flawlessly.